# Postgres full text search with multiple columns, why concat in index and not at runtime?

Tags: postgresql, search, indexing

I've come across full text search in postgres in the last few days, and I am a little confused about indexing when searching across multiple columns.

The postgres [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-tables.html) talk about creating a `ts_vector` index on concatenated columns, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX pgweb_idx ON pgweb 
    USING gin(to_tsvector('english', title || ' ' || body));
```

which I can search like so:

```
... WHERE 
      (to_tsvector('english', title||' '||body) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'foo'))
```

However, if I wanted to sometimes search just the title, sometimes just the body, and sometimes both, I would need 3 separate indexes. And if I added in a third column, that could potentially be 6 indexes, and so on.

An alternative which I haven't seen in the docs is just to index the two columns seperately, and then just use a normal `WHERE...AND` query:

```
... WHERE
      (to_tsvector('english', title) @@ to_tsquery('english','foo'))
    AND
      (to_tsvector('english', body) @@ to_tsquery('english','foo'))
```

Benchmarking the two on ~1million rows seems to have basically no difference in performance.

**So my question is:**

Why would I want to concatenate indexes like this, rather than just indexing columns individually? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both?

My best guess is that if I knew in advance I would only want to ever search both columns (never one at a time) I would only ever need one index by concatenating which use less memory.

---

**Edit**

moved to: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15412/postgres-full-text-search-with-multiple-columns-why-concat-in-index-and-not-at

Answer (score 6):

1. Using one index is easier / faster for a DB;
2. It will be quite difficult to properly rank results when using two indexes;
3. You can assign relative weights to columns when creating a single index, so that match in `title` will be worth more than a match in `body`;
4. You are searching for a single word here, what happens if you search for several and they appear separately in different columns?

Comment: #3 is really interesting - but I have no idea how to do this or where I can find out how - could you provide a reference or example?

Comment: There are still people wanting to know more about #3 :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of the implementation of #3, please see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/textsearch-controls.html:

> a weight is one of the letters A, B, C, or D

```
UPDATE tt SET ti =
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'')), 'A')    ||
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(keyword,'')), 'B')  ||
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(abstract,'')), 'C') ||
    setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(body,'')), 'D');
```